# Sorting Arrays and Finding Changes - Swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift, optimization

Okay, so I have a stream that is receiving an array at a fast speed constantly. Here's what I want to do...

If the array is the same, don't do anything. If it is different, make a new array with nil as every value except the changed ones.

Example:

Incoming array 1: [1,1,1,1]

Incoming array 2: [1,1,2,1]

I want to create: [nil, nil, 2, nil]. Only marking the changes.

I made something that worked, I just don't think it's efficient. Is it the best way to do it?

```
var storedArray = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0) //array for comparing

func incomingArray(data: [Int]) {
    if data == storedArray {return} //do nothing if its the same
    var tempArray = [Int?](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil) //nil array
    for index in 0...9 {
        if storedArray[index] != data[index] {
            tempArray[index] = data[index] //replace the temp array index               
            }
        }
    //send the completed tempArray to do work  ....

    storedArray = incomingArray //save the stored as the current data
    }
```

So the above code works. It's just not efficient. Any better ideas for this?

thanks

UPDATE 1:
I have mistaken in the original post. Instead of Int. They are UInt8.

Comment: You could modify [`SortedCollection`](https://github.com/natecook1000/SortedCollection). (See NSHipster's [collection protocols article](http://nshipster.com/swift-collection-protocols/) for more info).

Comment: How do you know it is not efficient? Did you measure it?

Comment: Is this example, I used a count of 10. My data count is much higher. And yes I did. Without the check, it averages 6% CPU. With it, up to 25% CPU. @St3fan

Comment: What is your actual data count?

Comment: The actual count is several hundred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the best answer. Instead of the whole empty nil array. I made my temp array a bool value. Then if the value changes, mark its index as true.

So here's a example.

Incoming array 1: [1,1,1,1]

Incoming array 2: [1,1,2,1]

I then export the full array plus a bool array of: [false, false, true, false].

Then I just check if theres a change and pull the value. It turned out to work much faster then the other answers. I also recycled the temp array to speed it up. My guess is that since it's value can only be true or false, it's a lot faster then NIL/UInt8.

Thanks for the help guys. Let me know if any other ideas come up.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to make this code faster:

1) Instead of using an array of `Int?`, use a plain `Int` and instead of marking elements as `nil`, mark them as some special integer value. I don't know what that value is, maybe 0 is fine, or -1, or `Int.max`.

> Update: The above change gives me a ~ 10% performance increase

2) Recycle your result array. So that you can skip the following code:

```
var tempArray = [Int?](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Or maybe better, let the caller pass it in via an `inout` parameter so that you don't have to worry about ownership of it.

> Update: The above change gives me a ~ 50% performance increase

Here is the code for all the versions suggested in this question:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

var storedArray1 = [Int?](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0) //array for comparing
func processIncomingArray1(data: [Int]) {
    var tempArray = [Int?](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil) //nil array
    for index in 0...9 {
        if storedArray1[index] != data[index] {
            tempArray[index] = data[index] //replace the temp array index
        }
    }
    storedArray1 = tempArray
}

var storedArray2 = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
func processIncomingArray2(data: [Int]) {
    var tempArray = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: Int.max)
    for index in 0...9 {
        if storedArray2[index] != data[index] {
            tempArray[index] = data[index]
        }
    }
    storedArray2 = tempArray
}

var storedArray3 = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: Int.max)
func processIncomingArray3(data: [Int], inout result: [Int]) {
    for index in 0...9 {
        if result[index] != data[index] {
            result[index] = data[index]
        }
    }
}

// Given two sequences, return a sequence of 2-tuples (pairs)
public func zip<A: SequenceType, B: SequenceType>(a: A, b: B)
    -> ZipSequence<A, B>
{
    return ZipSequence(a, b)
}

// Lazy sequence of tuples created from values from two other sequences
public struct ZipSequence<A: SequenceType, B: SequenceType>: SequenceType {
    private var a: A
    private var b: B

    public init (_ a: A, _ b: B) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    public func generate() -> ZipGenerator<A.Generator, B.Generator> {
        return ZipGenerator(a.generate(), b.generate())
    }
}

// Generator that creates tuples of values from two other generators
public struct ZipGenerator<A: GeneratorType, B: GeneratorType>: GeneratorType {
    private var a: A
    private var b: B

    public init(_ a: A, _ b: B) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    mutating public func next() -> (A.Element, B.Element)? {
        switch (a.next(), b.next()) {
        case let (.Some(aValue), .Some(bValue)):
            return (aValue, bValue)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}



func differences<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [Int] {
    // indexedPairs is a sequence of (index, (left-hand val, right-hand val))
    let indexedPairs = enumerate(zip(lhs,rhs))
    // the lazy may or may not help here, benchmark to find out...
    return lazy(indexedPairs).filter { (index, pair) in
        // only return different pairs
        pair.0 != pair.1
        }.map {
            // only return the index not the values
            $0.0
        }.array
}

var storedArray4 = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: Int.max)
func processIncomingArray4(data: [Int]) {
    let diffs = differences(storedArray4, data)
    if !diffs.isEmpty {
        // send new data and diff indices for further processing
        // then overwrite the old array
        storedArray4 = data
    }
}


func differences5<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [Int] {
    var diffs: [Int] = []
    // still using zip, since this guards against the two
    // arrays being of different sizes - doesn’t seem to
    // impact performance
    for (i,(l,r)) in zip(indices(lhs),zip(lhs,rhs)) {
        if l != r { diffs.append(i) }
    }

    return diffs
}

var storedArray5 = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: Int.max)
func processIncomingArray5(data: [Int]) {
    let diffs = differences5(storedArray4, data)
    if !diffs.isEmpty {
        // send new data and diff indices for further processing
        // then overwrite the old array
        storedArray5 = data
    }
}


class StackOverflowTests: XCTestCase {

    func testPerformanceExample1() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.measureBlock() {
            for i in 1...100000 {
                processIncomingArray1(data)
            }
        }
    }

    func testPerformanceExample2() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.measureBlock() {
            for i in 1...100000 {
                processIncomingArray2(data)
            }
        }
    }

    func testPerformanceExample3() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.measureBlock() {
            for i in 1...100000 {
                processIncomingArray3(data, &storedArray3)
            }
        }
    }

    func testPerformanceExample4() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.measureBlock() {
            for i in 1...100000 {
                processIncomingArray4(data)
            }
        }
    }

    func testPerformanceExample5() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.measureBlock() {
            for i in 1...100000 {
                processIncomingArray5(data)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @KareMorstol I haven’t benchmarked it, but I’d guess its extremely unlikely this will produce a speedup.  All it will do is reduce the size of the array by one byte, and comes at the cost of clarity – sentinel values like `-1` or `Int.max` are exactly that thing optionals are intended to avoid. Similarly, recycling the array probably won’t help much and introduces extra mutable state that could result in unexpected hard-to-debug behaviour.

Comment: I would agree with you about your Optionals comment if this was a more complex type. But in this case with an Int, a value type, I don't think it is bad to use a sentinel value. There is no danger. At least not the kind of danger that an Optional tries to solve.

Comment: @StefanArentz I eat my words, a quick benchmark suggests scrapping the optionals does give a marginal speedup.  Probably says more about the state of the Swift optimizer, as it feels like they should be near-identical (test a byte for null-ness vs test the integer for < 0).  I’d still be against it on readability grounds :)

Comment: I don’t think you’re comparing like with like.  In the case of `processIncomingArray3`, you don’t appear to be generating a list of differences (which was the original requirement).  All you’re doing is updating values in `result` that differ from the input array.  In all but the first iteration in your test loop, this won’t do anything at all since they’ll now be identical.  To replicate the original functionality, you need to do something that indicates which values have changed (so that some processing can be done on them).

Comment: I have mistaken in the question. It's actually a UInt8. Therefore nil has to be my only option. Also, all of the difference functions perform poorly. What do you mean by "Recycle your result array"?. I need to be reset after each process. I can put an else in to set it to nil, but it's also not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re concerned about performance, the first thing to look for is hidden loops.  Here’s one:

```
if data == storedArray {return}
```

This is presumably here for intended efficiency – if the two arrays are equal, don’t bother doing anything.  But really, this might be self-defeating.  That comparison isn’t constant time – it loops over the elements and compares them.  Since you’re going to loop over them later anyway, that probably doesn’t give you much.

You could argue it saves you allocating a new array, but this then leads to the next question which is do you really need to create an array with all those `nil` values?  Why not instead generate an array of the indices into the array that are different?  That way, the recipient of your differences will only have to loop over the differences (maybe only a couple) rather than the whole array.

It probably makes sense to factor out the array diffing from the processing and storage. Here’s a function that takes two arrays and returns an array of indices where they differ:

```
func differences<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [Int] {
    // indexedPairs is a sequence of (index, (left-hand val, right-hand val))
    let indexedPairs = enumerate(zip(lhs,rhs))
    // the lazy may or may not help here, benchmark to find out...
    return lazy(indexedPairs).filter { (index, pair) in
        // only return different pairs
        pair.0 != pair.1
    }.map {
        // only return the index not the values
        $0.0
    }.array
}
```

Note this is a pure function – that is, it takes inputs and produces a result without referencing any external state.  This makes it easier to test and debug as a standalone function.

You could then rewrite your original function in terms of it:

```
func incomingArray(data: [Int]) {
    let diffs = differences(storedArray, data)
    if !diffs.isEmpty {
        // send new data and diff indices for further processing
        // then overwrite the old array
        storedArray = data
    }
}
```

**Update**

Benchmarking suggests the filter/map version performs horribly, compared to a simple loop, so here’s a version of `differences` that just uses `for…in`:

```
func differences<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [Int] {
    var diffs: [Int] = []
    // still using zip, since this guards against the two
    // arrays being of different sizes - doesn’t seem to
    // impact performance
    for (i,(l,r)) in zip(indices(lhs),zip(lhs,rhs)) {
        if l != r { diffs.append(i) }
    }

    return diffs
}
```

Some quick tests suggests this version gets a significant speedup if the input is large and the # of differences small, but performs identically if the arrays are mostly different.

Comment: Can you provide some benchmark results? Curious what the speed difference is.

Comment: The trouble is that benchmarking this requires realistic data i.e. how sparse the differences are could make a big on performance (if the size of the array is many thousand elements, and the differences are just a couple of entries each time, this approach should be a lot better – especially depending on what is done with those differences).  OTOH if nearly every element changes every time, it’ll be little better or maybe worse.

Comment: This does not compile. Is `zip` not part of Swift 1.1?

Comment: I like this functional style solution, but I ran a benchmark and it is 27 times slower than my second suggestion where I move initializing and copying the result array out of the function.

Comment: @StefanArentz see my edit, `filter` appears to be the culprit (with or without `lazy`)  :-(.  `zip` was introduced in 1.2, but you can just replace it with the underlying struct, `Zip2`

Comment: The updated version is still 7 times slower than my second suggestion. I think the biggest overhead is creating the temporary array every time. I like elegant code, but I think in this case something less elegant but faster is more appropriate.

Comment: Can you post a gist of your code?  I’d be interested to play around with it.  What % differences are you assuming?  If there are almost no differences, the version that returns an array of only differing indices shouldn’t be creating more than a tiny array.  Also, have you tried 1.2?  Arrays apparently got a bit speed bump.

Comment: Added the code to my answer. Still on Xcode 6.1.1. Interested in finding out how 6.3 performs.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I tried both difference functions and they just aren't performing well at all. At one point, I hit 70% CPU. Like I said, It's processing this data very fast, and the array is several hundred, not 10.